# How can I stop another working webserver?

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, xampp

I get this error when I try to start Apache web server. I've been working on it for about a month and suddenly this error appeared today:

```
error::
xampp: another webserver is already running.
```

any suggestions?

Comment: do you know what webserver?

Comment: after applying command it shows that port 80 is listening to 1294/apache2

Comment: Well, then it looks like apache starts by default.  This is nice, since you won't have to start it on bootup.  You should be able to access the web content on port 80 already.

Answer (score 0):

You could check first which program is using port 80 (default http port) with :

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

And you will get something like

```
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:80    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    1547/nginx
```

For me is nginx, but it could also be apache2, lighttpd, or any other.

Next step is to now if it's running as service, which is an option in xamp.

```
service --status-all | grep nginx
```

If so, disable the service following instructions https://superuser.com/a/35160

If not, just kill the process, with `kill -9 PID`, being pid in the result from the first command, for me 1547 (1547/nginx)

Comment: it gives me 1294/Apache2, i followed the commands in the link provided above but still  nothing happens

Comment: Disabling the service during boot doesn't stop the service if it's currently running. Have you rebooted since you disabled it? If not, you can run `sudo service apache2 stop` to stop apache at runtime